# Getting TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, pickle

```
modell = Sequential()
modell.add(Dense(128, input_dim=5, activation='relu'))
modell.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
modell.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
modell.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
modell.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))


#Output layer
modell.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

modell.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
modell.summary()

modell.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, validation_split=0.2,batch_size=5, epochs =250)


pickle.dump(modell,open('model.pkl','wb'))
model=pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))
```

Using ann regression for final score prediction but getting the error:

> TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Pickle cannot handle Keras model objects.
Try using [Keras' save/ load](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize) instead ?

```py
model.save('path/to/location')
model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/location')
```